# Python + Selenium NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, selenium

I have an array of client on my website, built from my database. In each line of this array, I have a field fill with a link, where you can click on to be redirect on an other page (adresses are like this : localhost/display/client/{client_id})

I would like to make a loop test. For each iteration I get the n + 1 client ID, I click on the link and I compare the landing page with a string built from the ID I just got. The problem is that the number of my array line is not fix.

I made a test code :

```
    i = 1
    while self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='wrapper']/table[contains(@class, 'table')]/tbody/tr[" + str(i) + "]").text is not None:
        id = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='wrapper']/table[contains(@class, 'table')]/tbody/tr[" + str(i) + "]/td[1]").text
        self.assertEqual(i + 1, int(id))
        i = i + 1
```

It is working pretty fine, except that I have an exception coming from my stop condition line : `self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='wrapper']/table[contains(@class, 'table')]/tbody/tr[" + str(i) + "]")`

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='wrapper']/table[contains(@class, 'table')]/tbody/tr[7]"}
```

Seems like the "is not None" is not working and the loop fails. I didn't manage to find any intel about the return value of find_element_by_xpath() function.

Do you have any idea ? Thank you very much.

Comment: in short **//div[@id='wrapper']/table[contains(@class, 'table')]/tbody/tr[7]** is not there on the view you want to test, better way to do it is get the count of the number of elements in the list of WebElement

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you used the find_elements function to get a list containing all the rows you need. You can than just iterate over this list of rows.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to make it works by myself, using a try and an except, but I prefer your solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this before `While`, verify that element is enabled or displayed; can be achieved by:

for example:

```
element.isEnabled();

or 

element.isDisplayed();
```

if that's true, continue to next step or return. hope this will fix you issue

Answer (score 0):

If it can't find the element it throws an exception, before you can do `.text is not None`. Try this:

```
from itertools import count

for i in count(1):
    elems = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='wrapper']/table[contains(@class, 'table')]/tbody/tr[%s]" % i)
    if not elems:
        break
    self.assertEqual(1, len(elems))
    self.assertEqual(i + 1, int(elems[0].find_element_by_xpath("./td[1]").text))
```

The critical change is the `find_element`**s**`_by_xpath`, which doesn't throw an exception if no elements are found. However we also have to make sure that it doesn't return more than one element.

I've also gotten rid of the manual calculation of `i`, used basic string interpolation for the xpath, and found the `td` starting from the `tr` instead of the root.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late answer to your response. I did somehting similar : I added a try; except statement around my while and it works. I didn't not pimp my xpath because it was not my current problem ;D